# Polling an external application from Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, multithreading, long-polling, ruby-1.9.3

I'm finding it hard to find information on long polling from Rails 3. We have a situation where a mobile app requests something from a Rails JSON API, which in turn requests something from an external API. The external server holds a state that changes after ~30 seconds, and the Rails server needs to wait for that change and inform the application. Our two options, as I see it:

1. The mobile application polls the Rails server, by calling something like /resource/status. When the Rails server receives this request, it checks the status on the external server, and returns it to the mobile app, who decides whether the status is "ready enough"
2. The mobile application sends a request to the Rails server. The Rails server polls the external server (somehow), and whenever the status is "ready enough", sends a push to the mobile application

I understand the whenever gem for cronjobs, but this is more of a "do this every X seconds until it's ready" sort of thing... not really suited for a cronjob since the polling only happens over a short period of time. What I really need is a loop with a call to `sleep` in it. This method would have to create a new thread for each request, right? Is Rails suited to fit these multi-threaded needs?

There are a lot of articles online implying Rails and multi-threadedness do not mix, and some of it depends on what server you are deploying on, but it's hard for me to tell how valid these articles are, especially since some of them are over a year old.

So I guess the bottom line is: should we go with option #1, which seems to be the easiest option? Or #2, which makes more sense in that the server is doing all the work while the mobile app just waits for a push? If #2, what is the best way to perform this kind of long polling from Rails app?